# JavaScript Registration, Login and Logout Functionality

Tags: javascript, authentication, web, registration, logout

Basically I want a Login, Logout and Registration Functionality in my application using JavaScript

This is my Registration Page : https://i.stack.imgur.com/KY4vz.png
This is my Login Page : https://i.stack.imgur.com/IBEff.png

Comment: there is a lot of things that unclear here, I recommand you to try and tell us what did you tried and then we will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I can't find any question here.. if you want to find out how to validate forms using JavaScript just google it..

But my advice for login / register forms authentication is that it's must be done server-side and not on the client's side because if you will make it JavaScript like this:

```
var passInput = document.getElementById("passInput").value;
if(passInput == "correct password"){
//...
}
```

The client can just open the source code and simply see the correct password..

What you should do is to validate the form on server side so the client can't simply view the correct password.